# vslam algorithmic basis

Tags: ros, vslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

Regarding the vslam stack of ROS (http://www.ros.org/wiki/vslam), does anybody know what algorithms it uses for feature extraction, matching and so on? Is there any paper(s) I can read to understand how it works? I couldn't find anything related to these issues in the documentation of the stack.

Thanks!

Gazkune

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12624/vslam-algorithmic-basis/) by [gazkune](https://answers.ros.org/users/165/gazkune/) on ROS Answers with karma: 219 on 2012-01-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that it uses [SBA](http://www.ros.org/wiki/sba/Tutorials/IntroductionToSBA) (Sparse Bundle Adjustment).

It uses [g2o](http://www.ros.org/cgi-bin/mt-4.3/mt-search.cgi?IncludeBlogs=1&tag=vslam&limit=20) to optimize BA as much as possible.

[Here](http://www.ros.org/presentations/2010-08-Helen-VSLAM.pdf) is a great introduction to vslam.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3